# Layout widget resizing

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I'm having a problem with my Layouts in QT. Im trying to achieve a List of widgets which can be expanded and contracted in the following manner:

```
|------------|                                            |------------|
|Title 1     |                                            |Title 1     | Widget1
|------------|                                            |------------|
|QTextEdit1  |   Widget 1                                 |Title 2     |
|            |                                            |------------|                                                  
|------------|Which, by clicking on the title, contract:  |QTextEdit2  | Widget2
|------------|                                            |            |
|Title 2     |                                            |------------|
|------------|                                                       
|QTextEdit1  |
|            |   Widget 2
|------------|
```

The problem is, so far I've only be able to achieve the following: (After clicking on title 1)

```
|------------|                                                      
|Title 1     |                                                     
|------------|                                                       
|            |                                                      
|            |                                                                                                   
|------------|     
|------------|                                                       
|Title 2     |                                                 
|------------|                                                       
|QTextEdit1  |
|            |
|------------|
```

That is, I am able to make the QTextEdit of my first widget disappear, keeping the title height intact (this is important), but the second widget does not replace the space left by the first QTextEdit. It is as if the QTextEdit is still there, and the second widget cannot occupy that space.

I have tried setting a maximum height for the `widget1` when I construct it, but that doesn't seem to work. Oh, and each widget contains a QVBoxLayout, where a title and a QTextEdit are inserted, and then the list of widgets is another QVBoxLayout, where all the widgets are inserted.

Constructor:

```cpp
mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
QHBoxLayout *headerLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
title = new QLabel("My title!!");

m_arrowLabel->setPixmap(m_arrowDown);
m_activated = true;
title->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
title->setMaximumHeight(16);
headerLayout->addWidget(title, 0, Qt::AlignLeft);
headerLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

textEdit = new QTextEdit;
textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
textEdit->setText("My text!!!");
textEdit->setMaximumHeight(textEdit->document()->size().height() + 50);

mainLayout->addLayout(headerLayout);
mainLayout->addWidget(textEdit);
mainLayout->setContentsMargins(QMargins(0,0,0,0));
this->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Mouse Press event:

```cpp
event->accept();
if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
{
    if (m_activated)
    {
        m_activated = false;
        textEdit->setVisible(false);

    }else
    {
        m_activated = true;
        textEdit->setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

On my window where I populate it with widgets:

```cpp
m_mainLayout = QVector<QVBoxLayout *> (10);

for (int i=0; i<m_mainLayout.size(); i++)
{
    myWidget[i] = new myWidget;
    myWidget[i]->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    m_mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting a fixed vertical size policy for your widgets. This is why when you hide the text edit inside them, they won't shrink. Use `QWidget::setMaximumHeight` if you want to limit the height of the widgets.

Here is a small working example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    centralWidget()->layout()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
        widget->setMaximumHeight(200);
        widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Maximum);
        QVBoxLayout *w_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        widget->setLayout(w_layout);
        QHBoxLayout *top_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
        top_layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Title"));
        QPushButton *toggle_button = new QPushButton("Toggle");
        top_layout->addWidget(toggle_button);
        toggle_button->setCheckable(true);
        QTextEdit *text_edit = new QTextEdit;
        connect(toggle_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), text_edit, SLOT(setHidden(bool)));
        w_layout->addLayout(top_layout);
        w_layout->addWidget(text_edit);

        centralWidget()->layout()->addWidget(widget);
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Clicking the buttons will either hide or show the text edits of the widgets. The widget will shrink if the text edit is hidden and expand if it is shown.

Comment: Thank you!!
Also, the thing that was missing to keep all the widgets from expanding when I was closing one was to set QT::AlignTop to the mainLayout (which you did) :)

Comment: @gumlym Yes, the default layout alignment is center which is not very suitable for a list-like widget.